# IIS ASP.net Directory permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am encountering a strange behaviour on a windows web server.
I used to think that for a asp.net web application, the directory in which the application is stored has to be accessible for the user IUSR or the group IIS_IUSRS.

But on the windows server that is not the case.

The application pool of that app uses the Identity "ApplicationPoolIdentity",
but since the directory permission is missing the site should not run.

But it does.. :O

Does anybody know what is happening there ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the user "NetworkService". I haven't actually used IUSR in years.